# uthash delete and memory leaks, valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, uthash

I use [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_items_with_alternative_keys) hash table implementation with structs.

I have two hash tables, one of them (**dataTable** in code) collect some info in loop and when it finishes, save some of the data in the other hashtable (that is **stuffTable**). My program works(at least with small files) but when i check it with valgrind, it finds memory leaks for the second hash table(**stuffTable**) (but no leaks for the first table, eventhough i free it in same way)

```
    ==12075== Invalid read of size 8
    ==12075==    at 0x111CEE: deleteTable (myTest.c:1456)
    ==12075==    by 0x116AE6: getResults (myTest.c:1980)
    ==12075==    by 0x117E69: packetLoop (myTest.c:2350)
    ==12075==    by 0x1114C1: main (myTest.c:2872)
    ==12075==  Address 0x8335498 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 96 free'd
    ==12075==    at 0x4C2D16B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==12075==    by 0x111CE0: deleteTable (myTest.c:1458)
    ==12075==    by 0x116AE6: getResults (myTest.c:1980)
    ==12075==    by 0x117E69: packetLoop (myTest.c:2350)
    ==12075==    by 0x1114C1: main (myTest.c:2872)
    ==12075==  Block was alloc'd at
    ==12075==    at 0x4C2DF55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==12075==    by 0x112046: getStuffs (myTest.c:1475)
    ==12075==    by 0x116A75: getResults (myTest.c:1972)
    ==12075==    by 0x117E69: packetLoop (myTest.c:2350)
    ==12075==    by 0x1114C1: main (myTest.c:2872)
```

As you can see i only do malloc to create a new node and there are no other data structures in stuff struct for which i allocate memory. So i don't understand what causes memory leak. To delete hash table, i use standard procedure, given by uthash documentation:

```
void delete_all() {
  struct my_struct *current_user, *tmp;

  HASH_ITER(hh, users, current_user, tmp) {
    HASH_DEL(users,current_user);  /* delete; users advances to next */
    free(current_user);            /* optional- if you want to free  */
  }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
struct stuff {
      u_int32_t key;
      u_int32_t packets
      u_int32_t bytes;
      u_int32_t host;
      char name[16]; 
      UT_hash_handle hh;
    };

    struct stuff *myStuffTable = NULL;

    struct key_data {
      u_int32_t key;
      u_int32_t packets;
      u_int32_t bytes;
      u_int32_t count;
      struct triple top_host[A_SIZE];
      UT_hash_handle hh;
    };

    struct key_data *dataTable = NULL;

    struct triple {
      u_int32_t host;
      u_int32_t count;
      char proto[16];

    };

    static void deleteTable(struct stuff *dataTable) {
      struct stuff *current_key, *tmp;

      HASH_ITER(hh, dataTable, current_key, tmp) { //(myTest.c:1456)
        HASH_DEL(dataTable, current_key);
        free(current_key); //(myTest.c:1458)
      }
    }

    static void getStuffs(struct stuff **stuffTable, struct key_data *dataTable) {
      struct stuff *s;
      struct key_data *kd, *tmp;
      struct triple inf;


      HASH_ITER(hh, dataTable, kd, tmp) {
        s = (struct stuff *)malloc(sizeof(struct stuff)); //(myTest.c:1475)
        memset(s, 0, sizeof(struct stuff));

        s->key = kd->key;
        s->packets = kd->packets;
        s->bytes = kd->bytes;

        /* sort host array and take the first element */
        qsort(&kd->hosts[0], A_SIZE, sizeof(struct triple), triple_cmp);
        inf = kd->hosts[0];

        if(((inf.count > THRESHOLD) {
          s->host = inf.host;
          strncpy(s->name, inf.name, sizeof(s->name));
        }
        else
          s->host = 0;

        HASH_ADD_INT(*stuffTable, key, s);
      }

    }

    int main(){

            .....

            getStuffs(&myStuffTable, dataTable);
            deleteTable(myStuffTable);
    }
```

Comment: This is not a memory leak, perhaps there is a bug in your code and you fail to initialize something. In fact, it appears that you are deleting the same object twice.

Comment: You really want to annotate the code you show using the line numbers reported by Valgrind!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Wouldn't freeing memory twice be sort of an "inverted" leak? ;-)

Comment: @alk, i added where points line numbers as comments in the code. i hope it's clear.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: but you mean i delete it again in somewhere else? infact i call it just once, but program loops to collect info, save them and freeing structs...

Comment: Because you don't know how these loops work, just add a *print* statement to check how it goes.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use strncpy() it does more harm than good.

Comment: As you do not show the complete code: Does by any chance `deleteTable()` get called more then once?

Comment: @wildplasser what should i use instead of that? why it makes more harm?

Comment: i can't put the whole code here, it's too much line... But i tested it with print statement and actually it is called just once.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strncpy